# Fetch rows which belonging to the parent category which has more than two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some combination of company and members

```
Member Table
id  company_id companymember
1   1          john
2   1          Tam
3   2          haya
4   1          lee
5   3          kih
6   3          wild
7   3          cream 
8   3          earth
```

What I want to pick up is

`the 3 member names which belonging to the company which has more than two members`

What I want is like this

- company_id 2 has only 1 member, 3rd row is not selected
- company_id 3 has 4 members, so 8th row is not selected

My Goal

```
1   1          john
2   1          Tam
4   1          lee
5   3          kih
6   3          wild
7   3          cream
```

I could make it , pick up company_ids first and 
loop each id by script and fetch.

However in this way, it exec sql many times.

Is there any good way to do this on MySql by one sentence SQL??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select id,company_id,companyMember 
from (Select id
            ,company_id
            ,companyMember
            ,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY company_id ORDER By company_id) AS TotalCount 
      from MemberTable
     ) as Table1
where TotalCount <=3 and Company_id in(
                                      Select Company_id
                                      from MemberTable
                                      group by Company_id
                                      having COUNT(Company_id) >=3
                                      )
order by id
```

Comment: Does MySQL really support this?

Comment: SQL is a language, specified by ISO/ANSI. There are many products with SQL support, e.g. MySQL, Oracle and MS SQL Server, and none of them has full SQL support. Some has more, some has less.

Comment: Ahh sorry I mean I would like to do this in `one sql sentence` on `MySql`

Comment: I am trying now and found later half of this sentence works `Select Company_id
                                      from MemberTable
                                      group by Company_id
                                      having COUNT(Company_id) >=3` though, MySql doesn't have  Row_Numver()